# Converting Datetime to Time

Tags: sql, datetime

I have this code and I am trying to Convert Datetime to Time:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[GetBookingDetails]
@iDnumber nvarchar(50)
as

select 
    BookingNo,
    RoomName,
    CONVERT(Varchar(10), DATEADD(s,CheckinDate, '1970-01-01 00:00:00'),101 ),
    CONVERT(Varchar(10), DATEADD(s,CheckinDate, '1970-01-01 00:00:00'),101 ),
    Breakfast 
from Booking  
where  IDNumber= @iDnumber
```

But i get this error

> "Argument data type date is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd
>   function"

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with your convert statement.  DATEADD expects datepart, number, date.  Not datepart, date, date.

Comment: You're stating in several places you're trying to get a time from a datetime, but your schema and error messages indicate you're working with a DATE, not a DATETIME.  You can't get a time from a date, as it is only a date, not a datetime.

Answer (score 0):

From [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx):

> DATEADD (datepart , number , date )

You need to first show the part (second), then show a number (how many to add or subtract), and then finally show your actual date.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get a time from a datetime (and the date does not matter) you can do:

```
SELECT CAST(checkInDate as TIME)
```

note this may not work with all implementations of sql, but this looks like MS SQL - please tag your posts with your DBMS in the future (and even version if possible - as this solution doesn't work in all version of ms sql)

Comment: just changed it but it says "Explicit conversion from data type date to time is not allowed."

Comment: what datatype is checkInDate and what DBMS and version are you using?

Comment: wait... your checkinDate is an actual *DATE* type? not datetime?  You can't get a time from a DATE type, there is no time associated with it